# When do $k$ vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$? ($k>n$)

Tags: linear-algebra

My specific question I'm having trouble with is finding the values of $a$ for which $v_1=(1,3,4), v_2=(2,-1,1), v_3=(-3,5,a^2-2), v_4=(4,2,a+4)$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I'm relatively new to Linear Algebra, so I suppose there aren't many ways to solve this and I haven't seen any theorems which can help me. My approach was using definitions.

---

We need to find for which $a$'s, for all $\vec{x}=(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ exist $\gamma_1, \cdots,\ \gamma_4$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^4 \gamma_i v_i =\vec{x}$. Hence we get the system $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2  &  -3&  4& x\\ 
 3&  -1&  5&  2& y\\ 
 4&  1&  a^2-2& a+4   & z
\end{bmatrix}$ which reduces to $\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 0  &  7&  8& 7x+2y\\ 
0&  7&  -14&  10& -y\\ 
0 &  0&  a^2-4& a-2   & z-4x-y
\end{bmatrix}$
Here I got stuck and I'd like you guys to help me. We need a solution for this system so it has something to do which $a=2$ but I'm not sure what do I do with $x,y,z$?

---

My general question is about determining whether $k$ vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know if $k<n$ they don't span, and if $k=n$ then they span iif the vectors are linearly independent. What about $k>n$? is there a method/equivalent statement? Thanks and sorry if I did something wrong in advance (I know the rules here are pretty strict).

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the rank of the system of vectors is $n$. For this, you use row reduction. The rank is the number of non-zero rows after row reduction. Here I obtain:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&4\\3&-1&5&2\\4&1&a^2-2&a+4
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&4\\0&-7&14&-10\\0&-7&a^2+10&a-12
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&4\\0&7&-14&10\\0&0&a^2-4&a-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We obtain at once that if $a\neq \pm2$, the matrix has rank $3$, hence the $4$ vectors span $\mathbf R^3$.  More precisely, the first two vectors, along with the third or the fourth are a basis of  $\mathbf R^3$.

If $a=-2$, the reduced matrix is $\;\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&4\\0&7&-14&10\\0&0& 0&-4
\end{bmatrix}$ and it still has rank $3$. A basis is made up of the first two vectors and the last one.

If $a=2$, , the reduced matrix is $\;\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-3&4\\0&7&-14&10\\0&0& 0&0
\end{bmatrix}$ and it  has rank $2$.

Comment: First of all the at the bottom left it's 4 not 1 but it doesn't matter. Anyway, we didn't learn yet about the rank of a matrix (or more precisely the connection between amount of non-zero rows to the dimension of the column/row space, so this doesn't really mean anything to me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo! It's fixed now. Do you mean you know about row reduction and the augmented matrix, but not about its rank?!

Comment: Yea, we learned about it in the system of equations chapter. the only rank refrence we had was to determine the # of solutions (and we didn't even call it rank yet).

Answer (score 0):

The span the whole space iff $n$ out of the $k$ span the space. So you should check all possible $n$-tuples of vectors and see it one of them satisfies this requirement (this can be easily handled once you know what  determinants and minors are)

But once you have run the Gaussian elimination algorithm, the above is also easy to check: you just need to find $n$ pivots, or equivalently $n$ independent columns.

In your case, If $a\neq 2$, the first three columns (or the first, the second and the fourth) are linearly independent so you are done.

If instead $a= 2$ then you can easily see that the last entry of all columns will always be zero, so there is no chance that you will get the whole space, as for example the vector $(0,0,1)$ will not be a linear combinations of the given vectors.

Comment: First of all thanks. Now, we didn't learn that row/column space equivalent matrices is the same, so I doubt if I can use it. Isn't there a more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: The point is that to span R^3, the space spanned by a linear combination of [1 3 4] and [2 -1 1] can't be the exact same as the space spanned by [-3 5 a^2-2] and [4 2 a+4].

Comment: So I can take the cross product of each pair and demand they're different? EDIT: no that won't work..